# How to dividie entries into different pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have 30 entries, and I wish to divide them so that it only displays 3 of them on each page (and having many pages of course).

Currently, I have implemented it by passing a parameter in the URL and writing Ruby code in the action.

```
x = params[:id]
if x
  @problems = []
  x = params[:id].to_i
  t = Problem.all.count
  i = 1
  problem_numbers = -3 * (x - 1)
  while t > 0 do
    if Problem.exists?(i)
      problem_numbers += 1
      t -= 1
      if problem_numbers > 0
        @problems = @problems + [Problem.find(i)]
      end
    end
    if problem_numbers == 3
      break
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

It works quite well, but I think this piece of code might a bit complicated for such a feature; also if there are many entries, visiting pages would be slow because I counted through all the entries.

Is there a more convenient way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean pagination right? Checkout [will_pagine](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying items across multiple pages is called pagination. [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) are two very popular gems that provide this functionality in a way that is very easily integrated into Ruby on Rails applications.